# two icons in tabbar | reactnavigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add some icon (small circle) next to the tabicon. How can I do this?
Maybe some png above another. So I can give a visual feedback which connection is active

```
export default class ConnectionInfoScreen extends Component<{}> {
    static navigationOptions ={
        tabBarIcon:
            ({tintColor}: { tintColor: any }) => (
                <Image
                    source={require('../../assets/connect.png')}
                    style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
                />
            ),
    };

    render() {
        var isConnected = true;
        if (isConnected) {

            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>keine Verbindung</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }

        else {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>ConnectionInfo</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `activeTintColor` [tabBarOption](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarBottom-default-tab-bar-on-iOS) is used so that the icon can be rendered in a different color to indicate that it is active. Instead of tabBarIcon returning just an image, it returns some sort of Icon component which can be styled with color ([This](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) is an example of where you can get good icons like this).

---

**But if you want to stick with images:**

The tabBarIcon property is [defined](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarIcon) as :

> "[a] React Element or a function that given { focused: boolean, tintColor: string } returns a React.Node, to display in tab bar."

So, if you supply `focused` as a parameter, you can optionally display a different image as your tabBarIcon like this:

```
tabBarIcon:
        ({ focused,tintColor }) => {
            if(focused){
                return (
                    <Image
                        source={require('./focused-icon.png')}
                        style={styles.icon}
                    />
                )
            }
            else{
                return(
                    <Image
                        source={require('./not-focused-icon.png')}
                        style={styles.icon}
                    />
                )
            }
        },
```

Or, if you want to display another component (like a 'small circle') over your image:

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused,tintColor }) => {
  if(focused){
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require('./my-icon.png')}
          style={styles.icon}
          />
          <View name="active-indicator" style={{backgroundColor:'red',width:10,height:10,borderRadius:20,position:'absolute',top:-5,left:-5}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
  else{
    return(
    <Image
      source={require('./my-icon.png')}
      style={styles.icon}
    />
    )
  }
},
```